# Sqlite3.Open always returns CannotOpen

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to access skype local database using C# and sqlite but my tries always fail
Here is the connection code :-

```
StorageFolder sf =  Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
string k = Path.GetDirectoryName(sf.Path);
k = k.Substring(0, k.LastIndexOf('\\'));
k = k + '\\'+ "Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c" + '\\'+ "LocalState" + '\\' + "goldenwingsonline";
var path = Path.Combine(k, "main.db");
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path))
{
    string change = string.Empty;
    try
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

The code always returns CannotOpen within the sqlite class specifically at this line of code

```
var r = SQLite3.Open (databasePathAsBytes, out handle, (int) openFlags, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Although the path is correct but when i try to open it within file-explorer 
It 
[image: Error while opening main.db through file-explorer]

Any help please ?

Comment: This is a protected folder. Only the process that created it (Skype in your case) has access to it.

Comment: Try opening the folder in explorer; chop off the `main.db`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, this seems to be a Windows Store/Metro application which runs in a sandboxed environment. You cannot access files created in one application local storage folder from another.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yeh the folder opens just fine

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is there anyway to get around this ? like adding a future access permission or something ?
There is an app called "skyperious" that can access skype local database and show its contents ..

Comment: No, of course not, that's the whole purpose of isolating Windows Store applications's file system in a sandboxed environment so that only the app that created those files can access them.